# RPy2 Convert Dataframe to SpatialGridDataFrame

Tags: rpy2, r-maptools

how can a Dataframe be converted to a SpatialGridDataFrame using the R maptools library? I am new to Rpy2, so this might be a very basic question.

The R Code is:
coordinates(dataf)=~X+Y

In Python:

```
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
# Create a Test Dataframe 
d = {'TEST': robjects.IntVector((221,412,332)), 'X': robjects.IntVector(('25', '31', '44')), 'Y': robjects.IntVector(('25', '35', '14'))}
dataf = robjects.r['data.frame'](**d)
r.library('maptools')
# Then i could not manage to write the above mentioned R-Code using the Rpy2 documentation
```

Apart this particular question i would be pleased to get some feedback on a more general idea: My final goal would be to make regression-kriging with spatial data using the gstat library. The R-script is working fine, but i would like to call my Script from Python/Arcgis. What do you think about this task, is this possible via rpy2?

Thanks a lot!
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, Rpy2 is still unable to dynamically (and automagically) generate smart bindings.

An analysis of the R code will help:

```
coordinates(dataf)=~X+Y
```

This can be more explicitly written as:

```
dataf <- "coordinates<-"(dataf, formula("~X+Y"))
```

That last expression makes the Python/rpy2 straigtforward:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
sp = importr('sp') # "coordinates<-()" is there

from rpy2.robjects import baseenv, Formula
maptools_set = baseenv.get('coordinates<-')
dataf = maptools_set(dataf, Formula(' ~ X + Y'))
```

To be (wisely) explicit about where "coordinates<-" is coming from, use:

```
maptools_set = getattr(sp, 'coordinates<-')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Unfortunately I get the "ImportError: No module named packages". 

I work on Windows and use Rpy 2.08 and have read that the packages module is only available from Rpy > 2.1. However, those new versions are not Windows-supported(?).

Comment: There is a tentative contributed build against win32 for rpy2-2.2.4 in the bitbucket issue tracker. No public support for Windows otherwise (lack of contributions and lack of resource to dedicate to that from me, both being most likely linked).